# WebRTC: Switch from Video Sharing to Screen sharing during call

Tags: webrtc

Initially, I had two different webpages:

One was to do Video Call and
Other was to do Screen Sharing

Now, I want to do both of them in one page.

Here is the scenario:

During Live call, a user wants to stop sharing his/her video and start sharing screen.
Afterwards, again he/she wishes to turn off screen sharing and start video sharing.

For clarity, here are some questions I want to ask:

On Caller Side:

1) How can I change my local stream from video to screen and vice versa?
   2) Once it is done, how can I assign it to the local video element?

On Callee Side:

1) How do I handle if the current stream I am receiving is changed from video to screen?
   2) How do I handle if the stream I am receiving has stopped? I mean, now I can receive neither video nor screen (just audio)

Kindly, help me in this regards. If there are any open source codes available, kindly share their links too.

Just for your reference, I was trying to handle it using following code. (i know this is naive and won't work)

```
function handleUserMedia(newStream){

        var localvideo = document.getElementById("localvideo");
        localvideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(newStream);
        localStream = newStream;
        sendMessage('got user media');

        if (isInitiator) {
            maybeStart();
        }
     }

     function handleUserMediaError(error){
        console.log(error);
     }        

     var video_constraints = {video: true, audio: true};
     var screen_constraints = {video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: 'screen' } }};

     getUserMedia(video_constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);

     //getUserMedia(screen_constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);

     $scope.btnLabel = 'Share Screen';

     $scope.toggleSelected = function () {

         $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;

         if($scope.selected)
         {
             getUserMedia(screen_constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);
             $scope.btnLabel = 'Share Video';
         }
         else
         {
             getUserMedia(video_constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);
             $scope.btnLabel = 'Share Screen';
         }
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Check this demo:

- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/demos/switch-streams.html

#### and the relevant tutorial:

- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/how-to-switch-streams.html

### *simply renegotiate peer connections on both users' side!*

Comment: Thanks Muaz, it was very useful. What if I want to open multiple streams? I mean screen sharing and video at the same time.

Comment: You need to make two unique getUserMedia requests; on each request; you need to call "peer.addStream"....it means that you're trying to add two media streams to single peer connection....on target user side, "onaddstream" event will be fired multiple times according to number of streams you attached. Try another demo: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/demos/screen-and-video-from-single-peer.html

Comment: when I switch from audio/video stream to screen stream. It works perfectly fine. But screen stream does not take audio with it. Whenever I try to do it gives PermissionDenied Error. This one works

'var screen_constraints = {video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "screen" } }};'

but this one does not work

'var screen_constraints = {audio:true, video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "screen" } }};'

Why is it so?

Comment: Audio isn't permitted along with screen. The only workaround is to make multiple getUserMedia requests; one for capturing only audio; and one for capturing only screen.